# apache custom logs for different apps

Tags: logging, apache

in apache within the same virtual host, I have 2 paths

```
www.xxx.com
www.xxx.com/app2/
```

I want everything under app2 to be logged in a different file than the default. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate logs in Apache based on several different criteria.
Look at this page.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog

Add this to your httpd.conf ( I tried to add it to a virtual host conf but it didn't work)

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI app2/ app2-log
CustomLog "Logs/app2.log" common env=app2-log

CustomLog "Logs/access.log" common env=!app2-log
```

You ca use several different method to sepereate the logs.
One I'm using is to filer out GoogleBots access

```
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 66.249.78.242 googlebot-log
CustomLog "Logs/googlebot.log" common env=googlebot-log

CustomLog "Logs/access.log" common env=!googlebot-log
```

The problem is that I can only filter one IP at the time now but there might be a better way...

You can use these environmental variables listed here for filtering the logs
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/env_var.htm

I would like to use the DNS instead so I can catch all with a DNS ending with googlebot.com and place them into a separate file. But I don't now how to do that yet.

/Philip

**Edit**

I'm so stupid..  Of course my virtual host entry "didn't work" when I placed it into the wrong conf.
DOH!